# EditText.getLocationOnScreen() returns same result for 2 different positions

Tags: android, keyboard, position, android-edittext

I have a `dialog` with an `EditText`, and when the user clicks on it, the soft keyboard appears and pushes the `dialog` up (so as not to hide it). When the keyboard is dismissed, the `EditText` resumes its original position. This is standard behavior. The `EditText` has clearly moved, but calling `getLocationOnScreen()`, `getBottom()`, etc return the same result for both positions. Am I missing something here or is this a bug in Android?

By the way, the reason why I ask is because this behavior is causing some of our Robotium tests to fail, because Robotium relies on `getLocationOnScreen()` to calculate where to click.